# Calculating Goodness of Fit in Multiple Regression

Tags: regression, anova

[image]

I've never even heard the term "Goodness of Fit" in my class. I looked through the textbook and can't find it there either.

What exactly is "goodness of fit"? Is there a formula to calculate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to calculate the coefficient of determination (R square) which is the most common goodness of fit index in multiple regression and (multiplied by 100) denotes the percent of the variation of dependent variable explained by the 4 predictors participating in your model. I guess that you have a textbook to consult. If not then after a simple Google search you will find many excellent sources.

Answer (score 3):

Goodness of fit is, roughly, the ability of a model to generate high quality predictions.

To calculate the goodness of fit, the predicted values are called expected value $E$, and the outcome is called an observed value $O$. There are a number of tests based on comparing the observed values to expected values. They are generally some form of the statistic: $(E-O)^2/variance)$ where $variance$ depends on the type of outcome being modeled. This statistic trends toward a $\chi^2$ random variable with $q-p$ degrees of freedom. The numerator $q$ is the number of parameters needed to give the "observed" quantities in a model" and $p$ is the number of parameters in the candidate model. If the test achieves a $p$-value less than $\alpha$ we conclude that the model has poor fit and that the observed values are too inconsistent with the expected values.

The most commonly used goodness-of-fit test is the Pearson Chi-square test for categorical data which is calculated by:

$$ T = \sum_{i,j} \left( O_{ij} - E_{ij} \right) ^2 / E_{ij} $$

for a contingency table having row/columns indexed by $i$ and $j$. The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodness_of_fit) has a good discussion of these models. However, a Poisson model has a different goodness of fit metric, like $\sum O_i/E_i$ which Rockhill used to show [calibration of a cancer incidence prediction model](https://academic.oup.com/jnci/article/93/5/358/2906482) in 2001.

In an ANOVA with discrete fixed effects, there is a finite number of possible expected values, based on all observed combinations of covariates, so the test statistic of the form $\sum_{i=1}^k (\bar{Y}_k - \hat{Y}_k)^2/(\sigma^2/n_k)$ has an asymptotic $\chi^2_{k-p}$ distribution (please correct me if this is wrong). Here $\bar{Y}_k$ is the sample mean for the $k$-th combination of covariates whereas $\hat{Y}_k$ is the predicted mean and $\sigma^2/n_k$ is the expected variance of the $k$-th sample mean when homoscedasticity holds.

This method has been highly criticized.

1. Null hypothesis significance testing seems to have limited applicability for evaluating predictive models.
2. Split sample validation, cross validation, or bootstraps are more promising for evaluating predictive models.
3. Large samples tend to produce overly precise global "goodness of fit" tests.
4. High dimensional models can suffer from poor power.

Comment: I have never seen goodness of fit explicated as the ability to make good predictions, for me it mean that the data looks like what you would expect if you simulated from the simulated model. It could well be that the true model cannot make good predictions! But it could still be good-fitting

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I pondered the GOF for some time to think how best to explain in laymen's terms. I agree with your interpretation too. I don't see a disagreement between our explanations. I was careful about the word "good" versus "perfect" to describe predictions: good is relative to the realm of what's possible, a good fitting-model will certainly make good predictions if not perfect ones. A good fitting model may not be a true model.

Comment: @AdamO In the SEM tradition, you can have perfect fit with low R^2. In fact, it's often easier to get good fit when correlations among the original variables are low. But the OP is clearly asking about something different than SEM GOF, because (barring edge cases) a multiple regression model will always have perfect fit, being exactly identified. So apparently a subspecialty jargon difference.

Comment: @PatrickMalone how would one have perfect fit with low R^2 in SEM? There are many fit indices in SEM, they don't all measure the same thing. (Should this just be a separate question?)

Comment: @AdamO You can have a chi-squared of zero, which will be perfect fit by any criterion. The simple example is a saturated model (of which multiple regression is an example). It can reproduce the sample variance-covariance matrix exactly--which is what fit means in SEM--even when the relations are weak, so R^2 is low.

If you want to open a question I can hold forth further!

Comment: @PatrickMalone See related question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/340384/how-is-goodness-of-fit-estimated-in-sem-models).